# How to open email in Outlook using the Outlook addon?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing add-in where part of functionality is reminder. User entered some data and set what this email will be sent for example tomorrow.
My idea/task is to make possible what on pressing for example btn in my add-in it will open in Outlook(online one and desktop) the needed email.
What I have is id of the email that I need re-open in outlook. Is it possible if you know emails id in outlook open it again by add-in?
[image: Scheme or request]

Any ideas?

Btw I am using in my project newest version of `office.js.api` library for rest calls to Outlook. Also I know that in using gmail functionality you can open in same page needed email if you know its id.

Comment: So, you already know itemId of the email and you would like to open it in new window using a addin API. Is that correct? Can you please try this using this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-mailbox-displaymessageformasync-member(1)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT by new window you mean new webpage? I mean open it in outlook where addon is oppened.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT image to point my point https://i.imgur.com/zU1lMle.png

Comment: (1) By new window, I mean it opens a different popup Window where your other email will be seen. (2) I checked your screenshot. This is not possible currently where addin opens an existing email item and replaces current email item being shown (where addin is running). You can file a new feature request here explaining your scenario: https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT This method also opens `Sent` emails If I have there message ID?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-mailbox-displaymessageformasync-member(1) API requires item id and if we have it,we can open any message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to "Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT" answer was found.
The answer is using this function [displayMessageFormAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-mailbox-displaymessageformasync-member(1))
Be aware it uses as first prm `ItemId` member. [more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-messageread-itemid-member)

Like so

```js
let emailID ='AQMkADAwATMwMAItNGIxMy0yYTAyLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA5vuE8DX1vtBmAIURe25AdEHAENSlH9y8y9Jqcjhmi7n76AAAAIBCQAAAENSlH9y8y9Jqcjhmi7n76AAAAAJEhewAAAA'
 Office.context.mailbox.displayMessageFormAsync(emailID, function (asyncResult) {
  console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
 });
```

It opens it like so
[image]